# How to remove row in shown table by clicking on delete button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table that created by "HTML Helper" contain two columns the first column include file name and the second column include button with value "delete" , I want to remove the row by clicking on delete button ,
I tried to do this but it is not work 
this image contain on the code that used to create the table
[image]
and this image contain on JQuery code

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('#tb2').on('click', '.rmv1', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Or as you did, but actually calling the `remove` function:

```
$('#tb2').on('click', '.rmv1', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: if i want to remove this row from data base by clicking on the button what shoud i do >> in asp.net mvc .. have you idea ?

Comment: Don't know ASP.NET, sorry - But you can ask a new question about this (And don't forget the show what you have tried)